# TypeScript shared configuration object with typehinting

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-types

I am developing an API library and I am curious about how should endpoint configuration problem should be approached in Node.js with TypeScript. I want all endpoint configuration to be contained within one entity.

I currently have this approach in place:

```
ApiConstants.ts
------------------------
const BASE_DOMAIN = 'https://api.example.com';

export default Object.freeze({
  BASE_DOMAIN: {
    V1: `${BASE_DOMAIN}/v0.1`,
    V2: `${BASE_DOMAIN}/v0.2`,
    V3: `${BASE_DOMAIN}/v0.3`,
  },

  PATH: {
    CATS: '/animals/cats',
  },
});
```

It does the job, I can use it in any class by importing it and accessing the values. The problem is that I want to restrict functions to only accept values declared within this object. When request constructing function should display invalid type intellisense when value is passed which is not a part of this object.

Desired type would look something like this. Path must be declared within `ApiConstants.PATH` object.

```
function makeRequest(path: ApiConstants.PATH) {
  ...
}
```

How can such behavior be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function makeRequest(path: keyof typeof ApiConstants.PATH) {
  // ...
}
```

[See in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAQgQQMoFED6ARA8gWQQSQDkYBeGAcgAsooAHCALgHomBDWgSwDoBTAD1YBbWgBseXUIPIBuAFCzQkWAk4BhcNFZgoEUjCwAjAFY9gULgDMATjx4AvHgAoA3rJjxk6bHiIMYr93cANQBGPwADABJnRFRMXAJCAF8mADcABi4Q8IAaN0CggCYI6NivBKIUjK5C3PzggGYSmM94n2S0zIa69yS8-IAFBAAVAAk-AMDVEaQ-cjYwDkFWEQgmYFYdcjzevKSASjlZCwBXMDMOcBhlgGseACUeAEcTnmhHWk3KPzuATxALDAoL9aDwATAVBx1EotDouEMxvt-PkWDAuOjZEl5KiwCAYDwrFYQFYYIAUAhg02GSBgrBsMFSKw4ABNZLcHs9Xu9yJSkORDtimDAAAI6AC0-FBZnFhOJZJg2AA4tTaTwYBwwAyRMzWaw7o8Xm8oI5yIreYcgA)

In general, you probably want to do something like

```
const ApiConstants = Object.freeze({
  BASE_DOMAIN: {
    V1: `${BASE_DOMAIN}/v0.1`,
    V2: `${BASE_DOMAIN}/v0.2`,
    V3: `${BASE_DOMAIN}/v0.3`,
  },

  PATH: {
    CATS: '/animals/cats',
  },
});
type ApiConstants = typeof ApiConstants;

export default ApiConstants;
```

to avoid having to use `typeof ApiConstants` all the time. Note that this means `ApiConstants` is both a value and a type—Typescript is OK with this, and will know from context what you’re doing, but some programmers find it confusing. A common naming convention is to use an initial lowercase letter for the value, and an initial uppercase for the type, as in `const apiConstants = /*…*/;` and `type ApiConstants = typeof apiConstants;`.

On the other hand, it’s kind of convenient that your default export is both the value and the type.

You might also want to add

```
export type ApiPaths = keyof ApiConstants['PATH'];
```

We use `['PATH']` because we’re using the *type* `ApiConstants` here, not the *value*. We could still use the value but we’d have to add `typeof` to it again, as in `keyof typeof ApiConstants.PATH`.